# Thymeleaf request parameter null value problem

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a problem,my web app have a passcode form, user will give a Passcode string and app will riderict user to questions page for a spesific event. my controller will find this even by this passcode. i tried with this way but my passcode field is always null.

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/findEvent(passcode=${passcode})}">

    Passcode:<br>
    <input type="text"  th:name="${passcode}"><br>



    <div>
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/findEvent")
    public String resetPassword(@RequestParam(value="passcode",required=false) String passcode) {
        if(passcode==null)
            return "passcode";
        Event event=eventService.findByPassCode(passcode);
        List<Question> questions=questionService.findQuestionsByPasscode(passcode);
        return "questions";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String findEvent(@RequestParam("passcode") String passcode) {
        Event event=eventService.findByPassCode(passcode);
        List<Question> questions=questionService.findQuestionsByPasscode(passcode);
        return "questions";
    }
```

Same problem with mine

[Request parameter with thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305607/request-parameter-with-thymeleaf/58581475#58581475)
How can i achieve this ?? can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `name="passcode"` instead

```
<input type="text"  name="passcode" value="1234" />
```

Since its the same as the object name, just use

```
@RequestParam String passcode
```